# How do I working on two apps with different Ruby/Rails versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I finished Michael Hartl's tutorial and created an app using Ruby 1.92 and Rails 3.2. Now I want to make my own app but I want to use the new versions of Ruby and Rails.

If I install the new versions for my new app, can I still make changes to my old app without things getting messed up or do I have to keep installing/uninstalling different Ruby and Rails versions?

Comment: Use RVM in this case: https://rvm.io/rvm/install It will manage the Rubies you want (2.0 & 1.9.3 I guess) and the Gemsets for each project (gem Rails 4 and gem Rails 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at using a ruby environment manager. I use rbenv, you can also specify in your gemfile which version of ruby and rails should be used for a specific application.

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine. Just make sure the proper versions are specified in your `Gemfile` and you will be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

After installing the new version, by default new version will be used.  However, already existing app will still use the version of rails they already exist as.

Bundler takes care a lot of the hard work for you in your situation.

**Other notes**:
Keep in mind RVM allows you to install "Gemsets".  Should you have the need to use specific versions for gems you can create sets of them for use when needed.

You can also specify the version of rails when you're creating your app via `rails _3.x.x_ new FooBar` and you can identify what versions of rails are installed on your system via `gem list --local | grep rails`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to negotiate local and global ruby versions, consider using rbenv.
https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

RVM is another popular option for ruby environment management.
https://rvm.io/

Personally, I have been more successful with rbenv.